# How to get the google map location by getting the latitude and the longitude values from the database in laravel 6.x

Tags: ajax, laravel, google-maps, datatable, laravel-6

I have the latitude and the longitude values located in my database table, i have created a table where the users can filter the stores and the store location by selecting the values from the drop-down, i want to make a column which has a link for the users to click and find the store location in the google map. i have the latitude and the longitude values stored in my database, i don't know how can i add the link which will contain the latitude and the longitude value from the database and redirect the user to the google map and show the exact location,

Here's my Controller

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\StoreFC;

class StoreFCController extends Controller
{
     function index(Request $request)
    {
     if(request()->ajax())
     {
      if(!empty($request->filter_district))
      {
       $data = StoreFC::select('id','loc_type', 'loc_group', 'loc_code', 'location', 'location_2', 'status', 'latitude','logtitude','phone','address')
        ->where('location', $request->filter_district)
         ->where('loc_type', $request->filter_outlet)
         ->get();
      }
      else
      {
       $data = StoreFC::select('id','loc_type', 'loc_group', 'loc_code', 'location', 'location_2', 'status', 'latitude','logtitude','phone','address')
        ->get();
      }
      return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
     }
     $outlet_name = StoreFC::select('loc_type')
          ->groupBy('loc_type')
          ->orderBy('loc_type', 'ASC')
          ->get();

    $district_name = StoreFC::select('location')
        ->groupBy('location')
          ->orderBy('location', 'ASC')
          ->get();
     return view('test.store-fc', compact('outlet_name','district_name'));

    }

}
```

Here's my Model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StoreFC extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'store_foodcity';
}
```

Here's my table

```
<table id="store_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Outlet</th>
                        <th>Group</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Location 2</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Latitude</th>
                        <th>Logtitude</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

Here's the script to fill the Data table

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    fill_datatable();

    function fill_datatable(filter_district = '', filter_outlet = '')
    {
        var dataTable = $('#store_data').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax:{
                url: "{{ route('store-foodcity.index') }}",
                data:{filter_district:filter_district, filter_outlet:filter_outlet}
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data:'id',
                    name:'id'
                },
                {
                    data:'loc_type',
                    name:'loc_type'
                },
                {
                    data:'loc_group',
                    name:'loc_group'
                },
                {
                    data:'loc_code',
                    name:'loc_code'
                },
                {
                    data:'location',
                    name:'location'
                },
                {
                    data:'location_2',
                    name:'location_2'
                },
                {
                    data:'status',
                    name:'status'
                },
                {
                    data:'latitude',
                    name:'latitude'
                },
                {
                    data:'logtitude',
                    name:'logtitude'
                },

                {
                    data:'phone',
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        if (type === 'display') {
                        data = '<a class="gray" href="tel:' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    name:'phone'
                },
                {
                    data:'address',
                    name:'address'
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    // $('#filter_outlet').on('change',function(){
    $('#filter').click(function(){
        var filter_district = $('#filter_district').val();
        var filter_outlet = $('#filter_outlet').val();

        if(filter_district != '' &&  filter_district != '')
        {
            $('#store_data').DataTable().destroy();
            fill_datatable(filter_district, filter_outlet);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Select Both filter option');
        }
    });

    $('#reset').click(function(){
        $('#filter_district').val('');
        $('#filter_outlet').val('');
        $('#store_data').DataTable().destroy();
        fill_datatable();
    });

});
</script>
```

Now I'm Displaying the latitude and the longitude value from the database in the table.

This is how it looks links in the ui
[image]

i want to have an extra column with a link saying find location next to every stores which will redirect the users with the exact store latitude and the longitude value to the google map .

I hope my problem is understandable, please help me how can i do it, any tips ?

Comment: Do you want if clicked then show like this http://www.arrayconsortium.com/Covid19/covid-news

Comment: Yes, but it has many pin points. I want only one poi to be displayed. Or just load the location of the store using the latitude and the longitude values from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps is in a projected coordinate system that is based on the wgs84 datum. (EPSG 3857). For this reason, you can use directly the latitude and longitude.

To identify a business, Google Maps use PlaceID. To show the name's business, you need to know each PlaceID. I think you need to add this extra column for your database. (varchar type)

To search a PlaceID in Google Maps.
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

This is an example url in Google Maps with longitude,latitude and placeID ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide))
  https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393&query_place_id=ChIJKxjxuaNqkFQR3CK6O1HNNqY

To generate this url in your project. I think the cleanest option are put it on the model

```
class StoreFC {
  ...

  public function getGmapUrlAttribute() {
    return "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=".$this->latitude.",".$this->longitude".&query_place_id=".$this->place_id;
  }
}
```

To use in StoreFCController:

```
..
 function index(Request $request)
    {
     if(request()->ajax())
     {
      if(!empty($request->filter_district))
      {
       $data = StoreFC::select('id','loc_type', 'loc_group', 'loc_code', 'location', 'location_2', 'status', 'phone', 'address', 'gmap_url')
        ->where('location', $request->filter_district)
         ->where('loc_type', $request->filter_outlet)
         ->get();
      }
      ...
```

I hope this will be helpful to you. Cheers!